# How to play audio in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR9XO.png)

I import the library of players
I cant know what is the problem ?

how to play audio in flutter ?

I import the library of players
I cant know what is the problem ?

how to play audio in flutter ?

Answer (score -1):

To play audio in a Flutter app, you can use e.g the audioplayers package. Here are the steps to play audio in a Flutter app:

Add the audioplayers package to your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  audioplayers: ^5.1.0  # Use the latest version available at the time
```

Run flutter pub get to fetch the package.

Import the audioplayers package in your Dart file where you want to play audio:

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
```

Initialize an AudioPlayer object:

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
```

To play audio, you can use the audioPlayer.play() method. You need to provide the URL or file path of the audio file you want to play. Here's an example of playing audio from a URL:

```
String audioUrl = 'https://example.com/audio.mp3';

int result = await audioPlayer.play(audioUrl);
if (result == 1) {
  // Success
} else {
  // Error handling
}
```

You can also control the playback, pause, and stop the audio using the AudioPlayer methods. For example:

```
// Pause the audio
int result = await audioPlayer.pause();

// Resume the audio
int result = await audioPlayer.resume();

// Stop the audio
int result = await audioPlayer.stop();
```

You can listen to the audio player's state and handle events like completion or errors using callbacks:

```
audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((PlayerState state) {
  if (state == PlayerState.COMPLETED) {
    // Audio playback completed
  } else if (state == PlayerState.ERROR) {
    // Error occurred during playback
  }
});
```

Remember to manage the state of your audio player in your app's UI accordingly, such as displaying play/pause buttons and progress indicators.

Answer (score -1):

Because don't use `loadBytes before run`, let me write code here :

1- get bytes from asset :

```
final bytes = await AudioCache.instance.loadAsBytes('<write correct path ex: assets/note1.mp3>');
```

2- take bytes and set on BytesSource :

```
BytesSource(bytes);
```

3- run audio via play :

```
player.play(BytesSource(bytes));
```

Don't forget add `async` on function press